# Select and group MySQL column by certain word in result

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

I have some data in a database (which I'm retrieving via PHP) like so:

```
+----------------------+
| Browser              |
+----------------------+
| Chrome 23.0.1271.97  |
| Chrome 24.0.1312.52  |
| Chrome 26.0.1410.64  |
| Chrome 25.0.1364.172 |
| Chrome 25.0.1364.152 |
| Safari 8536.25       |
| Internet Explorer 8.0|
| Mozilla 5.0          |
| Internet Explorer 7.0|
```

What I'd like to be able to do, if it's possible, is to `SELECT`, `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` the browser type, regardless of whether the version number differs so that the ideal output would be:

```
| Browser           | Count |
+-------------------+-------+
| Chrome            |   29  |
| Safari            |   15  |
| Internet Explorer |   45  |
| Mozilla           |   20  |
```

I've tried various searches for different SQL commands that I may have overlooked or not known about to see if the results can be got from the database without needing to do something with them in PHP afterwards to group and count the results, but so far all I can get is the different browsers grouped and counted by their version numbers.

If it isn't possible, which is the best way to go about doing this with MySQL/PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(browser,' ',1) as browser, 
count(SUBSTRING_INDEX(browser,' ',1)) as count 
FROM browsers
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(browser,' ',1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group by the [substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) of `browser`, just using the first word in the column. The only issue I can think of is that `Internet explorer` will be returned as `Internet`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(browser,' ',1) as browser, 
       COUNT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(browser,' ',1) ) as count 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(browser,' ',1)
```

Comment: Yes, this is an issue I just noticed with it, but it can be easily remedied with PHP changing the result that = "Internet" to be "IE" in the result loop, unless there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT substring_index(browser,'',1),count(browser) as count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY browser
```

Answer (score 2):

This scirpt will work it is tested!

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( Browser, ' ', 1 ) AS browser, count( id ) as count
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY Browser
```